# i want to select DISTINCT (different) value

Tags: sql, select, distinct, distinct-values

i want to select DISTINCT (different) value from (itemof_shop.idreg_shop) column but it is not work.(mysqli)

```
select  distinct 
   itemof_shop.idreg_shop,
   itemof_shop.id
from
    itemof_shop
inner join reg_shop on
    itemof_shop.idreg_shop = reg_shop.id_shopOrgi
```

Comment: What result are you expecting and what result are you receiving? Please provide sample data. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i receiving duplicate value.DISTINCT  not effect .this query whit DISTINCT  and with out DISTINCT  gave me same result

Comment: @FaisalWahidi please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Without sample data it is impossible to say for sure, but when you use DISTINCT it will provide a distinct list of all the columns being returned. Since you have itemof_shop.Id in the select list, and id's are usually unique values, that is the reason you are not getting a distinct list of itemof_shop.idreg_shop. Remove the Id column from the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying distinct on ID that could be one of the reason you are not getting the desired result. By using distinct function you are able to obtain distinct values from a column.

Comment: Distinct is not a function, and it works on the whole selected rows.

Comment: when i select itemof_shop.idreg_shop . the result is 1 ,3,2,1,2,1,3,2,1 but i want to mysqli just return 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that you missing a lot of details elaborating your question, but a simple answer could be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [idreg_shop] FROM [itemof_shop]
```

Hope this helps, but if not, provide a clear path.

Comment: when i select itemof_shop.idreg_shop . the result is 1 ,3,2,1,2,1,3,2,1 but i want to mysqli just return   1,2,3

Comment: Hey Faisal if you really want some help, you need to start providing the minimum required details. Add table definition with sample data, and once that is complete the solution will fall in place.